# Webmin Windows Installer Reports no ActiveState Perl

Tags: compilation, webmin

I use Webmin on Ubuntu and like it but can’t get it to install on Windows using the Webmininstall.exe. It reports that Perl is not installed but I did install the 32bit ActiveState Perl in advance as required and it is in the system path. It is NOT installed in C:\Perl as I never let anything install directly in c:. Any ideas?

Comment: Looking at the Webmin.nsi file in the source code version, I see that the Perl path AND the Webmin installation path are hard-coded for some odd reason. I changed the paths in the file but how to I re-compile it to an executable? I can find nothing anywhere about that.

Comment: This appears to be a common problem but apparently no fix has ever been forthcoming. Has anyone ever gotten Webmin to work on Windows 10? I see no way it can be done as the WIN32-Daemon does not seem to be available anymore. If it CAN be done, please let me know!